# creating a calculator using features in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a calculator to calculate average price of Airbnb rooms, when we give neighborhood,beds, bathrooms, bedrooms counts as input(these features are already given in dataset)
neighborhood ,beds, bedrooms ,bathrooms and price are features in the dataset,,,please help

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provide more details and ask specific questions.

Calculating average price in pandas can be approached in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file.csv) # assuming the file has all the relevant fields

def calculate_price(row):
    return row['price_per_room'] * row['number_of_rooms'] * row['number_of_nights']

df['price'] = df.apply(calculate_price)

average_price = df['price'].mean()

print(f"The average price is {average_price }")

## use group by to aggregate across categories
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: def calculate_price(air_df): a = str(input("Enter the Neighbourhood : ")) b = str(input("Enter the Room Type : ")) c = float(input("Enter number of Beds : ")) d = float(input("Enter number of Bedrooms : ")) e = float(input("Enter number of Bathrooms : ")). I want  something like this ... I want to give inputs like for every values in those features and get the average price according to the input we gave... is it possible to make a calculator like this...please help ... I am new to programming..

Comment: Separate your code which takes these values from the user, and the code which does the calculation, and displays the result. Write separate function for these, and then use in the main code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's what you exactly need (you should specify your question a bit better, add sample data, preferred output, your code...), but groupby could be useful... Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'neighbourhood' : ['nice', 'not so nice', 'nice', 'awesome', 'not so nice'],
    'room_type' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
    'beds': [7,2,1,6,6],
    'bedrooms': [3,1,1,3,2],
    'bathrooms': [2,1,1,1,1],
    'price': [220,100,125,320,125]
})

print('Mean of all prices:\n', df['price'].mean())
print('\nMean grouped by neighbourhood:\n', df.groupby(['neighborhood']).mean().price)
print('\nMean grouped by more cols:\n', df.groupby(['neighbourhood', 'beds', 'bedrooms']).mean().price)
```

Output:

```
Mean of all prices:
 178.0

Mean grouped by neighbourhood:
 neighbourhood
awesome        320.0
nice           172.5
not so nice    112.5

Mean grouped by more cols:
 neighbourhood  beds  bedrooms
awesome         6     3           320
nice            1     1           125
                7     3           220
not so nice     2     1           100
                6     2           125
```

You can also filter the DataFrame before you apply groupy, i.e. like this:

```
# select requested data data in loc[...] and then apply groupby
df_filtered = df.loc[(df['neighbourhood']=='nice') & (df['beds']==1)]
df_filtered.groupby('neighbourhood')['price'].mean()
# or the same on one line:
df.loc[(df['neighbourhood']=='nice') & (df['beds']==1)].groupby('neighbourhood')['price'].mean()
```

And your function (from last comment) may look like this:

```
def calculate_price(air_df):
    a = str(input("Enter the Neighbourhood : "))
    b = str(input("Enter the Room Type : "))
    c = float(input("Enter number of Beds : "))
    d = float(input("Enter number of Bedrooms : "))
    e = float(input("Enter number of Bathrooms : "))
    return air_df.loc[
        (air_df['neighbourhood']==a) & 
        (air_df['room_type']==b) &
        (air_df['beds']==c) &
        (air_df['bedrooms']==d) &
        (air_df['bathrooms']==e)
    ].groupby('neighbourhood')['price'].mean()
```

Comment: what I want is , I want to crate a calculator like if I gave input neighborhood = nice, beds = 2, bedrooms  = 3... It should calculate the average price, on the basis of these inputs... can we do that is it possible..

Comment: @Aswin Babu, I've updated the example above. You just use loc for your conditions (select only data you need) and then calculate average price.

Comment: def calculate_price(air_df):
    a = str(input("Enter the Neighbourhood : "))
    b = str(input("Enter the Room Type : ")) 
    c = float(input("Enter number of  Beds : "))
    d = float(input("Enter number of  Bedrooms : "))
    e = float(input("Enter number of  Bathrooms : ")).                                                         @Lukas , bro... innate something like this ... I want to give inputs like for every values in those features and get the average price according to the input we gave... is it possible to make a calculator like this...please help ... I am new to programming..